# Exactly what does "range" mean in "to range the bride costume"?

Tags: meaning, australian-english

In a news article from Australia, a Kmart spokesperson said, "Kmart Australia regrets the decision to **range** the bride costume."

I checked various dictionaries including OED, but I could not find an appropriate explanation that makes sense in this sentence.

Is this a meaning unique in Australian English, or is this a typo?

Thanks!

Comment: This is actually a very interesting question. My first impression was that you hadn't done enough research, but, I too, cannot find anything to support it.

Comment: It's not normal Australian English, but maybe it's retail jargon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article refers to Kmart removing the costume after a petition was signed to have it removed.  Kmart is saying they're sorry to have included it in their range of products they carry.

I, too, cannot find a reference to this particular use of the verb *range*.  Even behind the paywall [Macquarie's Dictionary of Australian English](https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/features/word/search/?search_word_type=Dictionary&word=Range) doesn't have it.  However, I read the article and it's clear from context.

Comment: That's definitely a good answer. I found a similar but not identical definition from a New Zealand wholesaler which says "Product Ranging is the process we use to determine which products should appear on our supermarket shelves." This is maybe slightly different from the K-Mart usage but in the same area. https://www.foodstuffs-si.co.nz/media/98126/ranging_overviewdec17.pdf